# excel web add ins how to set the headerfooter?

Tags: excel-addins

I tried to use office.js to set headerfooter, but code error,

dev doc:
https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/javascript/api/excel/excel.headerfooter?view=office-js

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb225426(v=office.12)

my code:

```
function text() {

    Excel.run(function (context) {
        const myr = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sheet1");
        myr.HeaderFooter.centerFooter = "&Z";



        return context.sync();
    }).catch(errorHandler);
};
```

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!